# Login in with different Google accounts

Tags: python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I had a problem with my django website when switching between different Google accounts.

My django website uses social-app-django and Google OAuth2.0 for authentication. First, I login with a Google account(userA). Then, I logged out from my website and tried to log in with another Google account(userB). But I automatically login as userA when I pressed the login button. I had to clear all browser cookies manually in order to login as userB.

Some data was not cleared when userA logged out. What setting do I need to change? Or am I missing something?
I don't think disconnecting is what I am looking for. I just need to switch to different Google account.

*setting.py*

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
    'testLogin',    #Index page for testing social auth
    'social_django',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '***'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = '***'
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'

LOGIN_URL = '/auth/login/google-oauth2/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

#These are not default settings. Listed in case they might cause any problem
APPEND_SLASH=True
SESSION_ENGINE='django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },    
    'oracle': {
       ...
    }
}
...
```

*urls.py*

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('testLogin.urls')),    #Index page for testing social auth
    path('', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

*testLogin.html*    (Index page for testing social auth)

```html
...
<body>
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Logged as {{ user }}</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
  {% else %}
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">Login</a>
  {% endif %}
</body>
...
```

Comment: `python-social-auth` doesn't provide any means to sign users out from providers, that's out of the scope of the lib, take into account that if you sign the user out from Google, the rest of the google-based services will be also signed out, I would dislike that from any site. Still, if you need to do it, you will need to use their JS SDK to implement that functionality.

Comment: @omab I'm not trying to sign users out from providers. Using Stackoverflow.com as an example: a user can log in to Stackoverflow with a Google account, log out, then log in with a different Google account. That is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Then what you are looking for is enforcing the user account prompt, try with this setting: `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = { 'prompt': 'select_account' }`. More details at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#redirecting

Comment: @omab  Thank you. I this what I'm looking for. I tried using `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = { 'approval_prompt': 'force' }`, but I think `{ 'prompt': 'select_account' }` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

@omab answer works for other backends too.

I have tried with Azure AD and it worked:

```py
SOCIAL_AUTH_AZUREAD_V2_TENANT_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {"prompt": "select_account"}
```